# Retrieving page_description of a blog

Tags: shopify

On my site I've created multiple blog categories, and I'm displaying them all on a single page. I am trying to programmatically list each blog types title and description. The title works fine with `blogs.someblog.title` but I can't seem to get access to the data you input under the "SEO" section of of the CMS for this blog. Anyone know a way to get that info? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The meta description (under the SEO section) can be accessed via the `page_description` variable.

For example:

```
{% if page_description %}
<meta name="description" content="{{ page_description }}" />
{% endif %}
```

See [SEO for Theme Designers](http://docs.shopify.com/support/other/general-information/seo-for-theme-designers#meta-description) for more info.